# How to clear input fields in Angularjs after click of a button

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to clear a textbox and a select-list after a button is clicked.This is what I tried but it doesn't seems to work:

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntimeEvent.Comment" size="60" placeholder="ENTER IN ANY ADDITIONAL INFORMATION"/><br>
     <select class="categories" ng-disabled="selectlistdisabled"  ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntimeEvent.CategoryId" ng-options="downtimeCategory.CategoryId as downtimeCategory.CategoryName for downtimeCategory in Model.DowntimeCategories">     
   </select>
 <button ng-click="StopCurrentDowntime()">Stop Downtime Event</button>
```

JS:

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])

     .controller('DowntimeController', function ($scope, $http) {
         $scope.Model = new Model($http);

     $scope.StopCurrentDowntime = function () {
             $scope.CurrentDowntimeEvent.Comment = '';
             $scope.CurrentDowntimeEvent.CategoryId = '';
}
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305764/angularjs-clear-input-text-with-button

Comment: @Can Sahin Bakir I saw that link but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `Model.` in your JS

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('DowntimeController', function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.Model = new Model($http);

   $scope.StopCurrentDowntime = function () {
     $scope.Model.CurrentDowntimeEvent.Comment = '';
     $scope.Model.CurrentDowntimeEvent.CategoryId = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: Or simply `$scope.Model = new Model($http);` depending on what `Model` is. You could also use [`$injector.instantiate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#instantiate) instead of creating the Model by and, and let Angular take care of injection.

Comment: True, I just assumed that OP don't want to destroy existing model, I'll add your suggestion to my answer if you don't mind

Comment: @maurycy thanks a lot hey,I didn't realize that I had to put Model as well

Comment: @CaioToOn I didnot understand this, can you please explain Why we use `new Model`?

Comment: If you don't need to reuse the same instance, you can simply create a new one and expose in the scope. By doing that, and considering it will bring an empty object, it would clear the fields in the same way. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using button to clear input fields you can use reset (input type="reset") inside the form